# Magento 2 - Load Balancer - Health Check Failing - 302 redirect

Tags: magento2, redirect, curl, loadbalancing

I am having an issue with my load balancer health checks. It is attempting to access the server hosting the Magento 2 site. When I curl the IP address of the machine I get the following Response Headers:

```
curl -i xxx.xxx.xxx (ip address of the server)

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.example.com/?SID=79561247abvhemu78nosr0u32l
....
```

It appears to be redirecting to the domain set inside the Magento2 configuration.

I have read about the `SID` value. I am not sure if this is causing the redirect but the site will be a multi store site so I would like to keep the `SID` enabled.

The issue is that when the Load Balancer hits the server I am getting a `302` which causes the health check to fail.

I am unsure of what is causing this redirect and how to best get the health check to pass.

## Update

I have confirmed that it is Magento doing the redirect and not the web server. If I remove `index.php` and replace it with a new php file (Not running Magento) I get a 200 response. So it appears that something in the codebase is creating the redirect.

I ran `bin/magento config:show` and it returned the following:

```
web/seo/use_rewrites - 1
web/unsecure/base_url - https://www.example.com/
web/unsecure/base_static_url -
web/unsecure/base_media_url -
web/unsecure/base_link_url - https://www.example.com/
web/secure/base_url - https://www.example.com/
web/secure/use_in_frontend - 0
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml - 0
web/secure/base_static_url -
web/secure/base_media_url -
web/default/cms_home_page - home
web/cookie/cookie_path -
web/cookie/cookie_domain -
web/cookie/cookie_httponly - 1
web/url/use_store - 0
web/url/redirect_to_base - 0 
...
...
...
```

Plus a lot more config settings, that seemed irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the redirect is cause by the config setting `Auto-redirect to Base URL` from Stores->Configuration->Web->Url Options.

What this setting does it to redirect to the base url of your website any request that ends up in your magento instance.
For example making the request using the IP address like you do.
Setting this flag to 'No' should stop the redirects.

Comment: I have `Auto-redirect to Base URL` set to `No`. Any other settings that may cause this?

Comment: No other ideas. Maybe just clear the cache to make sure. Other than that, I got nothing.